# How to use two different index variables inside the same ngFor in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get a different set of index numbers for each items printing as Saturday only. As soon as Saturday starts to print, my value should start from 0 and it should go on. The other options should have the same value numbers. How do I achieve that?

[Here is my code in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2t4m6y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It's a blank project you shared with stackblitz

Comment: My bad. check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what the modulo has been created for ...

But to be clear : you can't have two indexes in your array. That's not even logical : if you did, don't you think they would have the same value ?

Instead, use the modulo (it's its name in French, I don't know if it's translated or not) :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <span *ngIf="i % 7 === 5">It's Saturday !</span>
</div>
```

Snippet :

```js
const days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
const month = [...days, ...days, ...days, ...days];

month.forEach((day, i) => {
  if (i % 7 !== 5) { return; }
  console.log(day);
});
```

**EDIT ONE** If you have an unordered array of days, the best way to "restart an index" is to split your array into several ones.

If you want to restart on saturdays, try something like this :

```js
array=["monday","monday", "tuesday", "wednessday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday", "saturday", "sunday"];
splitted = this.array.reduce((p, n) => {
  if (n === 'saturday') { p.push([n]); return p; }
  p[p.length - 1].push(n);
  return p;
}, [[]]);
```

```
    <p *ngIf="options != 'saturday' ">
      {{i}}. First category : Value{{i}}
      <p>
        <p *ngIf="options == 'saturday'" style="color:red">
          {{i}}. Saturday : Value{{i}}
        </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Here is your updated stackblitz.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8dtft?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**EDIT TWO** I hope this is it this time ! Simply create a counter with a getter, and initialize the counter to zero once the lifecycle is done.

```js
private counter;

get saturdayCounter() {
  return this.counter++;
}

ngAfterContentChecked() {
  this.counter = 0;
}
```

```html
<p *ngIf="options == 'saturday'" style="color:red">
  {{i}}. Saturday : Value{{saturdayCounter}}
</p>
```

[**Here is a working stackblitz.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vewafj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Not necessarily different index. Is it possible to have a different number series for a particular value occurance.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense whatsoever to me, so all I can tell you is "sure". Anyway, as you can see, simply use the modulo, which is made for your need.

Comment: What if Saturday in my array has multiple occuring. Will it still work?

Comment: Did you run the snippet ?

Comment: Yes, because saturday appears 4 times.

Comment: You are checking the saturday position specifically with the position of 5. It may not be the case always.

Comment: What if the days arrays is like : const days = ['Monday','Saturday,' 'Tuesday', 'Saturday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

Comment: That's because it's the 6th day of the week (and arrays start at 0 position). You can write a function to set the value of the modulo dynamically too, this would get rid of that "special case"

Comment: No No, The array is not filling in order of the days of the week. It can be any order.

Comment: Check the array of my stackblitz. Monday is coming twice in that array

Comment: I edited my answer and provided you a working stackblitz.

Comment: Did you checked my stackblitz. I have given a sample expected output.

Comment: Your stackblitz is showing all saturday values as 0

Comment: I didn't see the example output, sorry. I based my answer on your question, and I understood it that way. I'm editing my answer and blitz then.

Comment: I have edited my answer again @UdG, feel free to check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176569/discussion-between-udg-and-trichetriche).

Answer (score 0):

make a new array based in your "array"

```
let newArray:any[]=[];
let count:number=0;

this.array.forEach((a,index)=>{
   if (a=="saturday")
   {
     newArray.push({type:1,index:count});
     count++
   }
   else
     newArray.push({type:0,index:index});
})
```

Comment: If I do this way I would have to use another ngFor for this array. Right?

Comment: @UdG you could simply use your existing ngFor, and display `i` for the list order, and `item.index` for the value.

Comment: @UdG, yes, the *ngFor is < div *ngFor="let item of **newArray** >", not  < div *ngFor="let item of **array**" >. Moreover if you want to count array of one or another type you can use {{newArray.filter(f=>f.type==1).length}}.